# Difference between JVM and OS Interpreter?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to know what is the difference between java interpreter(JVM) and OS interpreter(Command Interpreter)?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the difference what you are looking for.

**CLI Interpreter**
The CLI interpreter has different syntaxes for different operating system. It normally is used to run other programs, and only a small amount of time is actually spent in processing the CLI statements.

**Java Virtual Machine with JVM**
The Java compiler converts the Java source code into an intermediate form called Java class files. The class files are the same for all operating systems. A great deal of checking for syntax errors and inconsistencies is done while creating the class file. The Java interpreter reads and executes the instructions in the class files.

The Just In Time Java interpreter JIT optimizes code that is run frequently, making execution much faster.